# Custom CSS not working alongside Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried to use a custom CSS file alongside my Bootstrap, but it's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">


  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>NRRN Concrete Udhyog</title>
</head>
```

On this section of the document, I tried to use my own custom CSS:

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="/Images /cover.jpg" id="slide-1-background" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide1">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5>First slide label</h5>
      <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS code:

```css
#slide-1-background {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: img with background-color ? Can you try some other css to see if it works ? like border etc..

Comment: aslong as an image will be displayed, it will obscure the background-color. as backgroudn images are placed on top of background-color layer-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It overrides the classes of Bootstrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- bootstrap css link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <style>
    
          /* -- Your custom css goes here -- */

          .custom{
          background: #000;
          font:10px 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
          color:white;
          }

        </style>  

  </head>
  
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning custom">Danger</button>
  </body>

</html>
```